# TypeScript tsc does not respond anything

Tags: reactjs, typescript, tsc

I'm new to TypeScript.

I was working on migrating my own React.js project which is written in JS into TypeScript.
I fixed all the bugs and also checked it worked well on `npm start`.
But when I tried to compile with tsc, it never works and never shows any of logs.
but as you can see, `tsc -v` works.

[image]

I tried Ctrl+Shift+B in VSCode, but it also showed same result, nothing.

[image]

in my `tsconfig.json`, I just added `outDir` into auto-generated `tsconfig.json`.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "outDir": "./dist"
  },
  "include": [
    "./src/*"
  ]
}
```

Is there anyway I can fix it?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you check 'dist' folder if there are any js files? The compiler could end silently without any output. Try to run it with '--extendedDiagnostics' option.

Comment: @Michal Yes I checked dist. no files exist. --extendedDiagnostics shows 283 files and 92063 lines... but idk it is right number

Comment: It looks like the 'noEmit' compiler option is the problem here. Set it to false or remove it since its default value is false.

Comment: @Michal oh, Thanks. It worked. Please add your comment as an answer. I will check that as right answer. I don't understand why CRA team made noEmit: true for default...

Comment: @Michal Ah.. I also found that `npm run build` only works when `noEmit: true`...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the app was created using CRA script, I would stick to the pre-existing script command 
`build` (npm run build) defined in package.json.

In this case, tsc is only used for type checking that's why `noEmit` is set to true. The `build` command executes `react-scripts build` script which behind the scenes uses Webpack to load and compile typescript to javascript.