# tsc compile in React (create-react-app) needs explicit compile flags altough I set them in tsconfig.json

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jsx, create-react-app, tsx

I first initialized a react app with "create-react-app" and afterwards added typescript to it with
`yarn add typescript @types/node @types/react @types/react-dom @types/jest`
I initialized tsconfig.json with defaults:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "esnext",
    "allowJs": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "noEmit": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "strict": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "./src/**/*.tsx"
  ]
}
```

If I try to compile single files like `tsc App.tsx` I get errors saying I need to use --jsx flag and --esModuleInterop flag. But I have set them in tsconfig.json already, why do I have to explicitely specify them in command line?
**It only works so: `tsc index.tsx --jsx preserve --esModuleInterOp`**
But why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html):

> tsc index.ts
>
> emits JS for just the index.ts with the **compiler defaults** (not the project's tsconfig)

And, you can't [specify file/s to compile and the tsconfig file](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/32323#issuecomment-510013098) on the CLI:

```
tsc index.ts tsconfig.json // NOT ALLOWED
```

So, if you are using CLI to compile just one or more files, you **must** provide the options (jsx and esModuleInterOp in this case) or [create new tsconfig file that extends the existing one, and add your file to it](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5858#issuecomment-255185701).

Comment: ok thanks and in what cases will my tsconfig.json be applied  when I compiile my whole project? or anyways in what case?

Comment: As I understand your question, first you setup a React project using CRA. And then you [added typescript](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-typescript/). So, now you can run the command `npm run build` or `yarn build` to create the React Build and the tsconfig file will automatically be used (by react-scripts and webpack) while building the project. Do you want something other than this?

Comment: See [TypeScript tsc does not respond anything](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58788246/2873538). If you want to see JS files compiled with tsconfig (for learning purpose), you need to remove the [`noEmit`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#noEmit) from tsconfig file or set it to `false`.

Comment: *"in what cases will my tsconfig.json be applied when I compiile my whole project?"*: Just run the command: `tsc` and it will find and use tsconfig file. Or do `tsc --project tsconfig.json`.